# jquery problem @.@

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('#save').click(
            function(){
                                alert('run');
                update_form('get_form','main_content',true);
            }
);
```

hi,i got a problem in my program..... please help me T.T.

above function is not run. i think the clue should be here.

```
$.ajax({
......
$('#' + divtoupdate).html("<input type='submit' id='save' name='save'  value='Save'/>");
})
```

all ajax part is ok, i think is because dom problem?,
the click() is created **before i run the ajax.(i have the action before i got the input)** is this causing click function malfunction. any solution for this problem ^^ thx

Comment: No matter how hard I try I don't understand a word from your question. Maybe the problem is with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes..for the click function on 'save' button to work...it should be present when page is loaded...try running click after ajax function..it should work fine then..
Even `Live` function will work --- It will take care of element even if it is added in future.

```
$('#Save').live('click',function(){
//ur code here
});
```

But Live will not work on older browsers.

Answer (score 2):

You should use [jQuery live](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use $.live to workout event handling on elements added dynamically.

```
$('#save').live('click', function(){ ... });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to say is that the first bit of code won't work because the second bit of code hasn't run yet. This second bit of code adds the HTML which the first bit works upon.

In which case, try the [live()](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCAQFjAA&url=http://api.jquery.com/live/&ei=edKiTa2lB5SAhAfYnNj_BA&usg=AFQjCNHPnKvzKaTw54m1H-YHMmd8NEWjTQ&sig2=Ecg_hAn3LCtEzqgygPmFBA) function instead of `click()`

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the click handler after the object is created.  You could just add your existing handler code to the ajax success, after the line where you create the #save element.

Answer (score 0):

Yeap, try putting your `$('#save').click` inside your ajax callback function.

```
$.ajax({
......
$('#' + divtoupdate).html("<input type='submit' id='save' name='save'  value='Save'/>");
$('#save').click(
            function(){
                                alert('run');
                update_form('get_form','main_content',true);
            }
); 
})
```

Answer (score 0):

try out this...add the function after you add the actual element...

```
$.ajax({
......
$('#' + divtoupdate).html("<input type='submit' id='save' name='save'  value='Save'/>");
$('#save').click(
            function(){
                                alert('run');
                update_form('get_form','main_content',true);
            }
);

})
```

Comment: thx but can i use bind and can explain abit y this will happen?^^ when i put this function inline it can work.

Comment: Your earlier code didn't work because the `onclick` handler was declared before the element even existed..so the handler was referenced to null....here you add it once the element is existing...now it is referenced and linked correctly

Answer (score 0):

$(document).ready(function() {
    var waterVolume
    function initialFill(){
        waterVolume = Math.floor(Math.random() * (150000 - 50000 + 1)) + 50000
        initialWidth = $('.resizable_tank').width()
        initialHeight = $('.resizable_tank').height()
        stabilizeWaterPipe(initialWidth,initialHeight)
    }

```
function stabilizeWaterPipe(currentWidth,currentHeight) {
    stableHeight = $('.resizable_tank_pipe').offset().top + $('.resizable_tank_pipe').height() + 8
    $('.stable_tank_pipe').css({height: (stableHeight-400)+"px", bottom: "-"+(stableHeight-400)+"px"})
    stabilizeCalc(currentWidth,currentHeight)
}

function stabilizeCalc(currentWidth,currentHeight) {
    stableTankWidth = $('.stable_tank').width()
    stableTankHeight = $('.stable_tank').height()
    increasedHeight = parseFloat(currentHeight - stableTankHeight)

    // im getting problem here with filling and make equal levels of water in both the cylinders would u pls help me with some code .
}

$('.resizable_tank').resizable({
    handles: 'e,s,se',
    maxWidth: 800,
    minWidth: 180,
    minHeight: 400,
    resize: function(event, ui) {
        var currentWidth = ui.size.width;
        var currentHeight = ui.size.height;
        stabilizeWaterPipe(currentWidth,currentHeight)
    }
})

initialFill()
```

});